# copy a character with specific length

Tags: c#, string

How can I fill a string with a specific character like make string and length like (y,4) and the result is  yyyy I know there is something like in c++, fillstring Is that exist in c# too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the appropriate [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx):

```
string text = new string('y', 4);
```

Comment: @Haedrian: I've already linked to it in the answer... (possibly after you went looking for it, but before you found it...)

Comment: I got ninja'd twice then, I'll remove the comment.